# Why is alloca different from just creating a local variable?

Tags: c, unix

I read that there is a funciton called alloca that allocates memory from the stack frame of the current function rather than the heap.  The memory is automatically destroyed when the function exits.

What is the point of this, and how is it any different from just crating an array of a structure or a local variable within the function? They would go on the stack and would be destroyed at the end of the function as well.

PS: I saw the other alloca question and it didn't answer how these two things are different :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `alloca` you can create a dynamic array (something that normally requires `malloc`) AND it's VERY fast. Here there are the advantages and disadvantages of GCC `alloca`:

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Variable-Size-Automatic.html#Variable-Size-Automatic

Comment: What do you mean by "GCC alloca"?

Comment: The `alloca` is normally defined as a compiler intrinsic. Often it isn't a "standard" function. I think it's the same in GCC. For example see this: http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca

Answer (score 10):

When you use `alloca`, you get to specify how many bytes you want at run time. With a local variable, the amount is fixed at compile time. Note that `alloca` predates C's variable-length arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following are different:

```
void f()
{
  {
    int x;
    int * p = &x;
  }
  // no more x
}

void g()
{
  {
    int * p = alloca(sizeof(int));
  }
  // memory still allocated
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a try, it would be an interesting difference :)  You're probably right since I think alloca mentioned having function scope.

Comment: It's quite likely that the memory is still allocated in both cases. The `x` *name* isn't available anymore, but the memory it represented is still allocated to the stack — the compiler doesn't generally adjust the stack pointer every time it enters or leaves a new scope.

Comment: @Rob: OK, increment the example to add further declarations after the block. In the first case, you'd reuse the memory for `x`, in the second you wouldn't...

Answer (score 1):

Until gcc and C99 adopted Variable-length arrays, `alloca` offered significantly more power than simple local variables in that you could allocate arrays whose length is not known until runtime.

The need for this can arise at the boundary between two data representations. In my postscript interpreter, I use counted strings internally; but if I want to use a library function, I have to convert to a nul-terminated representation to make the call.

```
OPFN_ void SSsearch(state *st, object str, object seek) {
    //char *s, *sk;
    char s[str.u.c.n+1], sk[seek.u.c.n+1]; /* VLA */

    //// could also be written:
    //char *s,*sk;
    //s = alloca(str.u.c.n+1);
    //sk = alloca(seek.u.c.n+1);

    char *r;
    //if (seek.u.c.n > str.u.c.n) error(st,rangecheck);
    //s = strndup(STR(str), str.u.c.n);
    //sk = strndup(STR(seek), seek.u.c.n);
    memcpy(s, STR(str), str.u.c.n); s[str.u.c.n] = '\0';
    memcpy(sk, STR(seek), seek.u.c.n); sk[seek.u.c.n] = '\0';
    r = strstr(s, sk);
    if (r != NULL) { int off = r-s;
        push(substring(str, off + seek.u.c.n, str.u.c.n - seek.u.c.n - off)); /* post */
        push(substring(str, off, seek.u.c.n)); /* match */
        push(substring(str, 0, off)); /* pre */
        push(consbool(true));
    } else {
        push(str);
        push(consbool(false));
    }
    //free(sk);
    //free(s);
}
```

There is also a dangerous usage of `alloca`, which is easily avoided by prefering VLAs. You cannot use `alloca` safely within the argument list of a function call. So don't ever do this:

```
char *s = strcpy(alloca(strlen(t)+1, t);
```

That's what VLAs are for:

```
char s[strlen(t)+1];
strcpy(s,t);
```